cargo build fails with "error: failed to build archive: no such file or directory" after adding any dependencies
I have a working Rust setup on Windows 11 and can run the hello world program with the PowerShell command line:
PS C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\trying-cargo\%TEST> cargo new helloworld
    Creating binary (application) `helloworld` package
note: see more `Cargo.toml` keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
PS C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\trying-cargo\%TEST> cd .\helloworld\
PS C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\trying-cargo\%TEST\helloworld> cargo run
   Compiling helloworld v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\trying-cargo\%TEST\helloworld)
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.19s
     Running `target\debug\helloworld.exe`
Hello, world!

But as soon as I try to add a dependency, say cargo add regex, then cargo run again, I get an error
PS C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\trying-cargo\%TEST\helloworld> cargo run
   Compiling memchr v2.7.4
   ...
error: failed to build archive: no such file or directory

I've tried this with several crates from crates.io and they all lead to the same error. What does this error message mean and how can I fix it?

So it turns out the issue was having a folder named %TEST in the file path. After removing the % character/symbol and trying again, things worked fine.
While looking into this, I learned about verbose output for cargo, and after examining the output of cargo -v -v run, I guess the % is being interpreted as a kind of variable substitution, as that's how it's done in batch files. I wasn't able to find any documentation about how this might affect PowerShell though, and still don't really know if this is a script bug in calling rustc or an argument parsing bug in rustc itself.

Found this closed issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2854 "it's a bug in LLVM"
